# how can i get no of red pixels and no of black pixels in PIL image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
pil_img=ImageGrab.grab([0,0,1000,1000])
```

Now I want to get no of red pixels and no of black pixels in two separate variables.So how should I proceed on pil_img[image: The image look likes this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much faster if you don't write a loop yourself over all the pixels.

```
import os.path
from collections import Counter

from PIL import Image

path_to_file = os.path.join('..', '..', 'img', '9BLW9.jpg')

# Count the number of occurrences per pixel value for the entire image
img = Image.open(path_to_file)
pixels = img.getdata()
print(Counter(pixels))

# Count the number of occurrences per pixel value for a subimage in the image
img = img.crop((100, 100, 200, 200))
pixels = img.getdata()
print(Counter(pixels))
```

With as a result:

```
Counter({(248, 8, 9): 1002251, (0, 0, 0): 735408, (248, 8, 11): 8700, (245, 9, 9): 7200, ...)
Counter({(0, 0, 0): 5992, (248, 8, 9): 1639, (3, 0, 0): 33, (0, 6, 0): 23, ...)
```

The fact that you have more than two pixel values is due to JPG artefacts. You could write some custom logic to see if a pixel resembles more black or red and count them as those as well.

Comment: Can you tell me how you were able to see my question.Initially it had not more than 10 to 15 views

Comment: I filtered on questions with the tag Python Image Library and saw your question in the list after scrolling down not too much.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pil_img.getpixel((x, y))`, or `pil_img[x, y]`.

Comment: It would be thankful if you upvote the question.I lost my previlege to ask question.:-(